# Calling library method inside .a file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, .a

I'm on Android Studio 2.1.3.

I've static library binary in .a file:

**libconfig.a**

I've the method signature that I need to invoke on the library:

**CLIENT_ConfigIPCWifi(szDeviceSN,  szSSID,  szSSIDPassword,  nWaitTime);**

Question: How am I going to call the method?

Answer (score 0):

You need an Android.mk file in your app/src/main/jni folder. It should look like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# This block is to make the NDK aware of your static library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libconfig
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path/to/libconfig/libconfig.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# This block is to build your C++ code that will call the method in the static library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ThatWillCallTheMethod
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cppFileThatWillCallTheMethod.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libconfig.a
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In your `jni` folder, you will have: `cppFileThatWillCallTheMethod.cpp`. And in that file you will call CLIENT_ConfigIPCWifi(szDeviceSN, szSSID, szSSIDPassword, nWaitTime); Somehow you will have to know which header files from libconfig.a that you need to include.

Hope this helps!